# Displaying an Error Message When Android App cannot connect to MYSQL

Tags: android

I want to display an error message when the MYSQL database can not be access due to sudden network disconnection how can i do this. Currently my application crash when this happens

I am using the below class to display the values to a Listview

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;


public class ViewActivity extends Activity  {



    ListView Listview;

    String url_get_All ="http://102.128.2.5/ABC/DisplayAll.php";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view);


        Listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);



        new GetAll().execute(new APConnect());

        View empty = findViewById(R.id.empty);
        Listview.setEmptyView(empty);

    }



    public void setlistArray(JSONArray jsonArray)
    {
        this.Listview.setAdapter(new ListAdapter(jsonArray,this));
    }

    class GetAll extends AsyncTask<APConnect, Long, JSONArray>
    {

        @Override
        protected JSONArray doInBackground(APConnect... params) {
            return  params[0].Getconnect(url_get_All);
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONArray jsonArray) {
            super.onPostExecute(jsonArray);
            setlistArray(jsonArray);
        }
    }

}
```

I have used the below Adapter class

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private JSONArray listArray;
    private LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    Activity cust;

    public ListAdapter(JSONArray jsonarray,   Activity cust)
    {
        listArray = jsonarray;
        this.cust = cust;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.cust.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.listArray.length();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ItemsinListCall call;
        // The view need to be setup
        if(convertView == null)
        {

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custodianrow_views,null);
            call = new ItemsinListCall();
            call.ID = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.id_view);
            call.Name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name_view);
            call.Desin = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Desig_view);
            call.Depar= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Depar_view);

            convertView.setTag(call);
        }
        else
        {
            call = (ItemsinListCall) convertView.getTag();
        }


        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = this.listArray.getJSONObject(position);
            call.ID.setText(jsonObject.getString("id"));
            call.Name.setText(jsonObject.getString("name"));
            call.Desin.setText(jsonObject.getString("Desin"));
            call.Depar.setText(jsonObject.getString("Depar"));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return convertView;

    }

    private class ItemsinListCall
    {
        private TextView ID;
        private TextView Name;
        private TextView Desin;
        private TextView Depar;
    }
}
```

And i have used the APconnect to connect to the webserver to access the PHP code

```
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;


public class APConnect {

     public JSONArray Getconnect(String url)
        {

            HttpEntity httpEntity = null;

            try
            {

                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

                httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();


            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



            JSONArray jsonArray = null;



                try {
                    String entityResponse = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);
                    Log.e("Entity Responce",entityResponse);

                    jsonArray = new JSONArray(entityResponse);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }



            return jsonArray;
        }
    }
```

I am getting the below error message

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.nms.ListAdapter.getCount(ListAdapter.java:35)
        at android.widget.setlistArray.setAdapter(ListView.java:486)
        at com.example.nams.ViewActivity.setlistArray(ViewActivity.java:80)
        at com.example.nams.ViewActivity$GetAll.onPostExecute(ViewActivity.java:140)
        at com.example.nams.ViewActivity$GetAll.onPostExecute(ViewActivity.java:110)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1265)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1081)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
return this.listArray.length();
```

To

```
return listArray==null?0:listArray.length();
```

And change

```
public void setlistArray(JSONArray jsonArray)
{
    this.Listview.setAdapter(new ListAdapter(jsonArray,this));
}
```

to

```
public void setlistArray(JSONArray jsonArray)
{ 
   if(jsonArray == null){
            //Show toast error
    }else
    this.Listview.setAdapter(new ListAdapter(jsonArray,this));
}
```

This is just my suggestion, you can make it better. You should split your task to many difference classes and one class will handle one task

Comment: Thankx ill do as what u have said